# Remove duplicates from multicolumns based on one column in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Remove duplicates based on **cont.id** then remove the whole line of same position of 
**cont.id, cont.name, cont.class**

```
var all_data = []
for (var i=0; i< data.class_ids.length ; i++) {
    var cont=data.class_ids[i];
    all_data.push(["",cont.id,cont.name,cont.classes]);
}
```

getting output like this 
**cont.id cont.name cont.classes**

A_1_VII VII V2 
A_1_VII VII V2 
A_1_VII VII V2 
B_1_XIV XIV V3 
B_2_XVI XVI v3

---

But I want like this
**cont.id cont.name cont.classes**

A_1_VII VII V2 
B_1_XIV XIV V3 
B_2_XVI XVI v3

Is there any way to do in html using **id=table_data & tr** then **check each tr** with **next row /tr and if same remove the next row from table data**
any help!!

Comment: use `array_unique`

Comment: I tried but not working, do you have any idea in html check updated question..

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help:

```js
var data = [
  {id: 'aaa', val1: 'sdfsd'},
  {id: 'aaa', val1: 'sdfsd'},
  {id: 'aaa', val1: 'sdfsd'},
  {id: 'bbb', val1: 'sdfsd'},
  {id: 'bbb', val1: 'sdfsd'},
  {id: 'ccc', val1: 'sdfsd'}
]

var woDuplicates = _.uniqBy(data, 'id')

console.log(woDuplicates)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the `id`s in a set, and then push an item into `all_data` only if its `id` doesn't exist in the set:

```js
var all_data = []
var ids = new Set();
for (var i = 0; i < data.class_ids.length; i++) {
  var cont = data.class_ids[i];
  if !ids.has(cont.id) {
    ids.add(cont.id);
    all_data.push(["", cont.id, cont.name, cont.classes]);
  }
}
```

For more information about javaScript sets, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Sets can be searched much faster than arrays.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is O(n²), and will have pretty bad performance if you have a large amount of data. Using a hash table to store the keys would result in O(n) performance.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK I've modified the code.. I think that it works well now

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `data.class_ids` data?

Comment: alert(data.class_ids); giving this output :

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Man, this doesn't help. Where are you getting `data.class_ids` from? Don't alert it. Just copy and paste it here.

Comment: after pushing into `all_data` array, values stored like this
`,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,B_1_XIV,XIV,V3,,B_2_XVI,XVI,V3`

Comment: after everyline there is one extra comma in the `all_data` array, probably this is its not able to figure out the duplicates.
Used ur code & also tried this too `var uniq = [ ...new Set(all_data) ];`

Comment: both are not working above codes. Or can you do like this, creating three separate arrays for each column, make unique first array by giving index to the positions then remove the duplicates then use those indexes which are deleted, to remove the other array items by using same indexes in other 2 columns